# Delete all indices in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

does anyone know where I can find all the data that I imported to elasticsearch through logstash? Where are they stored? I want to delete all indices but cant find them anywhere. When I try to delete them in Kibana, they are still there. 
I just downloaded zip files from Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana and run in directly from the batch file. Did not use any installation.There is a folder data in the elasticsearch folder, i can see the indices , even if I delete them from there, they are still somewhere and taking so much disk space. Any solution for this? Im working on windows 10.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by deleting indices in Kibana (what do you do exactly?)

Comment: I was meaning Indexes, sorry. Delete them from Saved Objects. My Disk Space is full from all the stuff that I ingested through logstash, cant find them in my laptop and delete them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your comment, you clarified that what you are deleting in Kibana is not actual data, but only the index patterns (that's what you have in "Saved Objects") - see [Kibana documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html).

If you want to delete data from Kibana, you would need to go to the **Dev Tools > Console** page (see [Kibana documentation | Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html)), and use the [Delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) to delete your indices. E.g., by running something like

```
DELETE <your_index>
```

If you don't know the names of your indices, you can run first the following command in the Dev Tools > Console:

```
GET _cat/indices
```

Comment: You can also delete all indices with `DELETE * ` (unless you disable wildcard deletes), but be careful — this will really remove everything including the `.kibana` index with all your visualizations, dashboards,...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script to delete certain indices programmatically from Opensearch, it is pretty risky to go for the delete all option, that's not recommended.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl --request GET \
  --url https://<domain>/_cat/indices \
  --<auth headers>
  
cat temp | awk '{print $3}' | grep <filterterm> > list

cat list | while read line; do 
 echo Removing index: $line ..;
 curl --request DELETE \
  --url https://<domain>/$line \
  --<auth headers>
done
```